# How do I start and use wxPython?

Tags: python, scripting, wxpython

I downloaded wxPython from the website, but I don't know how to start it. I have the main folder and in it is:

```
Lib
Scripts
unicows.dll
```

How do I start it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you are running in windows I would download the wxPython setup file

from your terminal

```
C:> python
```

then

```
import wx
a = wx.App(redirect=False)
d = wx.MessageBox("Hello World!!","Hello!")
```

then start reading the docs

Comment: It says 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. I doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Download the Documents and Demos package from the web site, install it, read the documents and try the demos.  *(You did download and install python first if you are on windows didn't you)*